# Haskell sqlite3 json

Tags: json, sqlite, haskell

I am trying to to create a simple Haskell app that gets the data from the API and then inserts them into the database (sqlite3). I have managed to sucessfully get the data from my API and create the database.  However, the issue I face at the moment is how to extract these data out of JSON and insert it into the database. I cannot share all the details that's why I modified the types (data) structure. Sample API response:

```
[{"name":"John","surname":"Terry","workPlace":"Bank","accountBalance":124344.08,"age":44}]
```

Person Data Type and its instance (for extraction) :

```
    data Person = Person
               {

                  name :: Text, 
                  surname :: Text,
                  workPlace :: Text, 
                  accountBalance :: Rational, 
                  age :: Integer 
               }
               deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Generic, ToJSON )



instance FromJSON Person where
   parseJSON (Object v) = p <$> n <*> s <*> w <*> acc <*> a
       where p = Person             
             n = v .: "name"
             s = v .: "surname"
             w = v .: "workPlace"
             acc = v .: "accountBalance"
             a = v .: "age"
   -- A non-Object value is of the wrong type, so fail.
   parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd do it the same way you insert anything into a database. Source doesn't matter once you have the values you need.

Comment: Can you scope your problem a little more narrowly and with more complete details?  From my reading you already have values of type `Person` and wish to create a database entry into some unspecified database library, perhaps `sqlite-simple`, perhaps `sqlite`, or `sqlite-direct`, or perhaps something else.  It seems the talk about JSON is all superfluous.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. The thing is, I need to assign the values from json to variables so I can insert the values stored in these variables into the database, right? And my problem is that whenever I try to convert json to the object, I end up with IO() format and I have no idea what I am supposed to do next in order (and it would make it accessible. ) to feed my db with the data. I am a beginner when it comes to Haskell, so I might be missing something.

Comment: If your problem is with IO, please edit the question and include the code where you are doing IO.  If you have code that can write a Person to the database, include that also.

Comment: It is not the IO problem though. IO is the last thing I got to, but it still does not change the fact that the thing I want to understand is how can I extract the data from a JSON so it can be assigned to variables and then inserted into the database. Thanks.

Comment: I followed [this tutorial](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/json) - first example, but there is nothing about what should happen next once the JSON file is decoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the issue I face at the moment is how to extract these data out of JSON and insert it into the database.

Those are two separate issues.

1. You have a `FromJSON` instance for your type so all you need to do is `decode` or `eitherDecode` to parse your JSON into the `Person` type:

   ```
    case eitherDecode person_json of
       Left err     -> error err
       Right person -> insertPersonIntoDB person
   ```
2. You haven't selected an sqlite library.  Select one and read how to use it.  I've picked sqlite-simple which can be used as such:

   ```
    do
    conn <- open "test.db"
    execute_ conn "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people\
                  \ (name TEXT, surname TEXT, workPlace TEXT,\
                  \ accountBalance INTEGER, age INTEGER)"
    execute conn "INSERT INTO people \
                 \(name,surname,workPlace,accountBalance,age)\
                 \ VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
            (name,surname,workPlace,accountBalance,age)
    close conn
   ```

Later, in a comment you said:

> I need to assign the values from json to variables

That is what the decode does, it parses the JSON into the Person value and by pattern matching on Person we can get variables for each JSON field.  For example:

```
printPersonTuple (Person nm sur wk acct years) =
    print (nm,sur,wk,acct,years)
```

> so I can insert the values stored in these variables into the database

Yes, once you have variable names, or just a `ToRow` instance (read the sqlite-simple docs) then you can insert the value into the database.

> And my problem is that whenever I try to convert json to the object, I end up with IO() format

Well that is a very separate problem from anything in your question.  Post that as another question if you are stumped.

**Conclusion**

It appears you have several problems such as understanding IO, decomposing the problem into subcomponents, using a value after parsing, selecting and groking a database library.  Please see below for a complete example but it probably won't be completely illuminating given this list of things to learn - please do ask follow up questions not as comments to this answer but as fresh questions separate from this one.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards   #-}
import GHC.Generics                     -- So you can derive 'Generic'
import Data.Aeson                       -- JSON
import Database.SQLite.Simple           -- Databse ops
import Data.Text (Text,unpack)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BC -- Just for prettier debugging

-- The type you are receiving from JSON
data Person = Person
           { name           :: Text
           , surname        :: Text
           , workPlace      :: Text
           , accountBalance :: Integer
           , age            :: Integer
           }
           deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON )
          -- To/FromJSON are autogenerated JSON encode/decode instances

-- Auto-convert database rows into Person types for queries
instance FromRow Person where
    fromRow = Person <$> field <*> field <*> field <*> field <*> field

-- An expensive "insert" operation
-- Open a DB connection, create a table (maybe), insert the value, close the
-- connection
insertPersonIntoDB :: Person -> IO ()
insertPersonIntoDB (Person {..}) =
 do conn <- open "test.db"
    execute_ conn "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (name TEXT, surname TEXT, workPlace TEXT, accountBalance INTEGER, age INTEGER)"
    execute conn "INSERT INTO people (name,surname,workPlace,accountBalance,age) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)" (name,surname,workPlace,accountBalance,age)
    close conn

-- A simple test to print out the whole table
printDB :: IO ()
printDB =
 do conn <- open "test.db"
    res <- query_ conn "SELECT * FROM people" :: IO [Person]
    putStrLn (unlines (map show res))
    close conn

-- Glue it all together by
-- 1. Make the json 2. parse the json 3. insert to DB 4. print entire DB
main :: IO ()
main =
  do let person_json = encode (Person "Tom" "MD" "Galois" (floor 1e9) 4)
     putStrLn $ "JSON: " ++ BC.unpack person_json
     case eitherDecode person_json of
        Left err     -> error err
        Right person -> insertPersonIntoDB person
     putStrLn "----- Database -----"
     printDB
```

And the result looks like:

```
% ghc so.hs
% ./so
JSON: {"accountBalance":1000000000,"age":4,"name":"Tom","workPlace":"Galois","surname":"MD"}
----- Database -----
Person {name = "Tom", surname = "MD", workPlace = "Galois", accountBalance = 1000000000, age = 4}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas. That's exactly what I was interested in!